# Menu-button is missing when custom style is set

Tags: java, android, themes

Within my app there is a possibility to set a bright and a dark theme beside the default system theme. These two additional themes are defined  via a style definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <style name="DarkTheme" parent="android:Theme.Black">
 </style>
 <style name="LightTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
 </style>
</resources>
```

But as soon as I use one of these themes, the menu-button (the three dots below of each other) are gone and I no longer can access this menu.

Adding a statement

```
<item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
```

does not help. So...what is missing here exactly, how can I keep my menu button also when a different style is set?

Thanks!